# Appendix package option to force page break before appendices

Tags: page-breaking, appendices

Instead of manually putting a `\newpage` before `\begin{appendices}`, how can I tell the appendix package to do this ?

Answer (score 15):

If you have a chaptered document class, this would be the default behaviour. In documents with top level structure `section` there is no way to tell the `appendix` package to insert a page break. That is because sections usually do not start new pages. So you need to manually add a `\clearpage`.

Answer (score 1):

The `etoolbox` package provides commands for inserting commands around/within environments.
I've included some related (commented) commands you may find useful.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Inserts \clearpage before \begin{appendices}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\clearpage}
% Inserts \clearpage after \end{appendices}
%\AfterEndEnvironment{appendices}{\clearpage}

% Inserts \clearpage before every \section within appendices environment
%\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\pretocmd{\section}{\clearpage}{}{}}{}

\begin{document}
    \section{Pre1}
    \section{Pre2}

    \begin{appendices}
        \section{App1}
        \section{App2}
    \end{appendices}

    \section{Post1}
    \section{Post2}
\end{document}
```